# MEAN- mongoose - getting parent id for subdocument (returns undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having little issues populating sub document with my angular service

I tried with postman and I think I'm getting the right result from the backend...

the isuue is:

- I need to get comments from a single article displayed
- I have referenced comment model and all in my article model
- I have each comments _Id object in my articles model
- I think the Issue I'm having now is my angular service that connect to the api endpoint to get my desired result...

The API endpoint getting the comments of an article

```
//get all comments for an article
router.get('/:articleId/comments', function (req, res, next) {
    Article.findOne({ _id: req.params.articleId })
        .populate('article, articleId')
        .populate('comments')
        .exec(function (err, comments) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occured getting the articles\'s comment',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Succesfull',
                obj: comments
            });
        });
});
```

My article service getting the comments for each article

```
    getComments() {
        const articleId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['articleId'];
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:7777/article/' + articleId + '/comments')
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const comments = response.json().obj;
                const transformedComments: Comment[] = [];
                for (const comment of comments) {
                    transformedComments.push(new Comment(
                        comment.body,
                        comment.username,
                        comment._id,
                        comment.articleId
                    ));
                }
                this.comments = transformedComments;
                console.log(transformedComments);
                return transformedComments;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
```

Response from postman request

```
http://localhost:7777/article/5b1d0659cee09b0ca4d79147/comments 


{
    "message": "Succesfull",
    "obj": {
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5b1d0674cee09b0ca4d79148",
                "body": "how about it scoffield",
                "username": "McAndi",
                "articleId": "5b1d0659cee09b0ca4d79147",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5b1d1129cf9e7830a80bbf9c",
                "body": "shes feeling me down below",
                "username": "McAndi",
                "articleId": "5b1d0659cee09b0ca4d79147",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5b1d1e57df754307e45d4ef4",
                "body": "slay mamas won yapa sibe",
                "username": "McAndi",
                "articleId": "5b1d0659cee09b0ca4d79147",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "favoritesCount": 69,
        "_id": "5b1d0659cee09b0ca4d79147",
        "title": "Jaded",
        "description": "Ejanla Surface, the koko is loaded, infact the gbedu has landed ✈",
        "body": "Ejanla Surface, the koko is loaded, infact the gbedu has landed ✈Ejanla Surface, the koko is loaded, infact the gbedu has landed ✈",
        "username": "McAndi",
        "userId": "5b1735fe5821ba1fe801d5ba",
        "__v": 3
    }
}
```

The article comments component where I made use of the `getComments()` service

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ArticleService } from '../../article.service';
import { User } from '../../../auth/user.model';
import { Comment } from '../../comment.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-comment-list',
  templateUrl: './article-comment-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-comment-list.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ArticleCommentListComponent implements OnInit {
  private User: any;
  article: any;

  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService, ) { }

  comments: Comment[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.getComments()
      .subscribe(
        (comments: Comment[]) => {
          this.comments = comments;
        });
  }
```

In my application, if I should navigate to `:articleId/comments`, the `articleId` becomes undefined... which is the main issue I'm having now`
below is the error result from console

```
{title: "An error occured getting the articles's comment", error: {…}}
error
:
kind
:
"ObjectId"
message
:
"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Article""
name
:
"CastError"
path
:
"_id"
stringValue
:
""undefined""
value
:
"undefined"
__proto__
:
Object
title
:
"An error occured getting the articles's comment"
__proto__
:
Object
```

the url in my browser becomes

```
http://localhost:7777/article/undefined/comments
```

I actually can't say this is where the mistake or error is, but any heads up will be well appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: The problem is of course where `const articleId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['articleId'];` is undefined. How are you actually setting the route data? Is there a link or something else which should be setting this? Or at least show the action where you even get to the `getComments()` method. Since this is clearly happening in your angular code, then you don't actually need all the other tags on the question, or any of the other code since you have already verified the back end works as it should.

Comment: I'm actually new to MEAN development, and I've used the `const articleId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['articleId']` in getting single articles, I dont really understand your point boss, are you talking about where I used the `getComments()` service??

Comment: What I'm asking you is "why should there be any value in the `snapshot.params`"? What makes you think you are putting anything in there? Show where you believe the `'articleId'` to actually be set. The rest of what I am telling you is relevant to "asking a question of your peers". Don't include the parts not directly relevant to the question which you already know work, and instead show us the "missing parts" where you are actually interacting with the "route" in the Angular code.

Comment: I've added the comments component... and in my article details route, I added `data` attribute to save my `articleId`...something like `data: {articleId: 'articleId'}`, I actually don't know if thats holding the articleId data... please share if there's a better way I can go about it. Thanks for helping...